# How GZIP compression will take place inside asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, gzip, pagespeed

I was working on page optimization in my asp.net application using [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/payload) and came across that i need to compress all request to Gzip format to reduce size and load time.

However when i have checked requests in network it's shows me that in **Request-header** & **Response-Header** there is already **Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch** and **Content-Encoding:gzip** respectively. That means encoding is automatically take place for aspx page!

**How this was happened? Is it by default?**

For js and css there is no encoding and in **PageSpeed Insights** it shows me that you need to compress all **js** and **css** as well in High Priority section. **How can i achieve it for my asp.net application?**

Answer (score 1):

IIS is able to do gzip compression for you, example below goes into your web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <!-- enable gzip compression -->
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true" />
</system.webServer>
```